# Beginner c# - Windows 10, WPF, Resource Dictionary, ContextMenu, & Task Bar Icon - Problem with MenuItem Visibility

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Quick question (with a quick answer I hope) about WPF, Context Menu.

I'm struggling with the MainWindow closing when the "X" is clicked. As the app currently stands I have successfully implemented a TaskBar Icon using WPF NotifyIcon (http://www.hardcodet.net/wpf-notifyicon) and a ContextMenu pop up when the right mouse button is clicked. The data for the context menu is provided by a XAML resource directory with the menu item visibility set to visible. The visibility of the menu items changes depending upon which is clicked, i.e. minimize or maximize. The methods for switching the visibility is in the .cs for the XAML and simply sets Visibility to Collapsed or Visible, and also hides/shows the main window. The resource Directory is implemented at the App level so that in theory all the properties and variables are visible globally.

I have tried several ways to have the "X" of the main window alter the menu item visibility but so far no joy. The application is working so far, apart from the "X" button. The context menu items are not accessible as I expected and I am unable to create an exception handler for when the main window closes as the resource directory is loaded before the main window is created.

I have taken several different approaches prior to the attached, including binding, events, triggers, interfaces, etc... There is probably something simple that I am overlooking.

Thanks.

Code as follows...

App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="ShareDealer.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ShareDealer"
         Startup="Application_Start"
         Exit="Application_Exit"
         ShutdownMode="OnExplicitShutdown">

    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="TrayMenu.xaml"/>
    </Application.Resources>

</Application>
```

App.xaml.cs

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for App.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class App : Application
{
    [DllImport("user32", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string cls, string win);
    [DllImport("user32")]
    static extern IntPtr SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
    [DllImport("user32")]
    static extern bool IsIconic(IntPtr hWnd);
    [DllImport("user32")]
    static extern bool OpenIcon(IntPtr hWnd);

    private TaskBar tb;

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        PresentationTraceSources.Refresh();
        PresentationTraceSources.DataBindingSource.Listeners.Add(new ConsoleTraceListener());
        //PresentationTraceSources.DataBindingSource.Listeners.Add(new DebugTraceListener());
        PresentationTraceSources.DataBindingSource.Switch.Level = SourceLevels.Warning | SourceLevels.Error;
        base.OnStartup(e);
    }

    private void Application_Start(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        bool isNew;
        var mutex = new Mutex(true, "MyWindowsMutext", out isNew);
        if (!isNew)
        {
            ActivateMainWindow();
            Shutdown();
        }

        tb = new TaskBar();
        // Custom icon
        new MainWindow().Show();
        MainWindow.Icon = BitmapFrame.Create(Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Icons/ShareDealerIcon.ico", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)).Stream);
    }

    private void Application_Exit(object sender, ExitEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Exit Event Raised", "Exit");
    }

    private static void ActivateMainWindow()
    {
        var other = FindWindow(null, "OnlySingle");
        if (other != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            SetForegroundWindow(other);
            if (IsIconic(other))
                OpenIcon(other);
        }
    }
}
```

TrayBar.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="ShareDealer.TaskBar"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:tb="http://www.hardcodet.net/taskbar"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ShareDealer">

    <tb:TaskbarIcon
        x:Name="TaskBarTray"
        IconSource="Icons/ShareDealerIcon.ico"
        ToolTipText="Share Dealer" 
        MenuActivation="RightClick"
        ContextMenu="{StaticResource ResourceKey=TaskBarTrayMenu}">
    </tb:TaskbarIcon>
</UserControl>
```

TaskBar.xaml.cs

```
public partial class TaskBar
{
    //public TrayMenu TrayMenu = new TrayMenu();
    //public ResourceDictionary TrayMenuResourceDictionary = new ResourceDictionary();
    
    public TaskBar()
    {
        //TrayMenuResourceDictionary.Source = new Uri("TrayMenu.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        //Resources = TrayMenuResourceDictionary;
        InitializeComponent();            
    }
}
```

TrayMenu.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary x:Class="ShareDealer.TrayMenu"
                x:ClassModifier="public"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    
    <ContextMenu x:Key="TaskBarTrayMenu" x:Shared="true" Name="TaskBarTrayMenu">
        <MenuItem  Click="TrayMin" Name="TrayMinVis" Header="Minimize" Visibility="Visible" />
        <MenuItem  Click="TrayMax" Name="TrayMaxVis" Header="Maximize" Visibility="Collapsed" />
        <MenuItem  Click="TrayExit" Header="Exit"/>
    </ContextMenu>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

TrayMenu.xaml.cs

```
public partial class TrayMenu : ResourceDictionary
{
    public TrayMenu()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Application.Current.MainWindow.Closing += MainWindowClosing;
    }

    public void TrayExit(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Current.Shutdown();
    }

    public void TrayMin(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.TrayMinVis.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        this.TrayMaxVis.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        try
        {
            Application.Current.MainWindow.Hide();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception Caught - Trying to hide window when it is not visible.");
        }
    }

    public void TrayMax(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.TrayMaxVis.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        this.TrayMinVis.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="ShareDealer.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ShareDealer"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="500">    
    <Grid></Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();         
    }

    protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        Hide();
        e.Cancel= true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO!  Are you sure that the MainWindow is closed?  How do you know?  I don't see that you've implemented the override of OnClosed.  When I took your code, and added OnClosed, I noticed my breakpoint never gets to that method.  So the main window is hidden, but it is not closed.

Comment: Or maybe I'm not understanding what your problem is exactly, or what you're trying to do when you click "X" button.

Answer (score 0):

- Instantiating a Control in the background only fires an Initialized
  event.
- Most custom controls don't take effect until after the Loaded event.
- So, you can try like this.

  ```
   <window>
     <local:TrayBar/>
   </window>
  ```